# What does "cynical confidence" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english, word-order

I know that cynical means something along the lines of believing the worst in people, but how does this word coincide with confidence? For instance, what would this line mean?

> The witness had a cynical confidence.

I'm lost on how to interpret this phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is used in **To Kill a Mockingbird**

> The witnesses for the state, with the exception of the sheriff of Maycomb County, have presented themselves to you gentlemen, to this court, in the **cynical confidence** that their testimony would not be doubted, confident that you gentlemen would go along with them on the assumption— the evil assumption that all Negroes lie, that all Negroes are basically immoral beings, that all Negro men are not to be trusted around our women, an assumption one associates with minds of their caliber.

This context helps explain why a **witness** could be considered cynical. They confidently believe that the court, the judge or the jury will believe their **false testimony**.

Here's an example expanding on your sentence. Definitely not from To Kill a Mockingbird.

> *The witness had a cynical confidence* as he thought the jury were fools who would believe anything said by a man wearing such a magnificent moustache!